# Cannot redirect to a file - no error

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I am trying to write a file from the output of the script with the following command:

```
. script.sh > file.dat
```

After the command has been launched a zero byte file is created. File is not listed as open (lsof). If the file.dat is changed to some other name outputs gets written without any issue.

Comment: What are the contents of `script.sh`?

Comment: Could it be that your script outputs to [tag:stderr] instead of [tag:stdout]?  In which case you can do `. script.sh &> file.dat` to capture both the [tag:stdout] and [tag:stderr] streams.

Comment: In the script I am doing some modification and outputing a file (cat filex). The problem is solved if the file is created inside the script however from outside it does not work.

Comment: Problem solved. Mistake was made in outputing a file that I was writing to (ex.: cat a>a)